# Getting “Cannot call a class as a function” in my React Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

I am trying to connect my react app to firebase, it was working perfectly befor connecting it to firebase, now I am getting this error:

Clients

src/components/clients/Clients.js:16:8

```
if (clients) {
return (
<div>
<div className="row">
<div className="col-md-6">
<h2>
```

here is my Clients.js code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { compose } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { firestoreConnect } from "react-redux-firebase";

import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Clients extends Component {
  render() {
    const clients = this.props.clients;

    if (clients) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <h2>
                {" "}
                <i className="fas fa-users" /> Clients{" "}
              </h2>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">---</div>
          </div>

          <table className="table table-striped">
            <thead className="thead-inverse">
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Balance</th>
                <th />
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              {clients.map(client => (
                <tr key={client.id}>
                  <td>
                    {client.firstName} {client.lastName}
                  </td>
                  <td>{client.email}</td>
                  <td>${parseFloat(client.balance).toFixed(2)}</td>
                  <td>
                    <Link
                      to={`/client/${client.id}`}
                      className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
                    >
                      <i className="fas fa-arrow-circle-right" /> Details
                    </Link>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return <h1>Loading</h1>;
    }
  }
}

Clients.prototype = {
  firestore: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  clients: PropTypes.array
};

export default compose(
  firestoreConnect([{ collection: "clients" }]),
  connect((state, props) => ({
    clients: state.firestore.ordered.clients
  }))
)(Clients);
```

How can i solve that problem ? it's first time for me to try fire base.
I am using "react-redux" version 5.1.1 and "react-redux-firebase" version 2.2.4.

Comment: I don't understand you, what do you mean ?

Comment: Which version of react-redux do you have. Can you tried to switch the order of parameters in the compose: I already had strange issue with connect and some others HOC.

Comment: @Kornflexx I've version 5.1.1 of react-redux. I've tried to switch the order of parameters in the compose but it still giving the same errors.

Comment: Do you use react-router ?

Comment: @Kornflexx, yes I am using react-router

Answer (score 0):

You seems to use react-router.

In your router .js file, change this:

```
<Route path="/" render={Clients} />
```

To this:

```
<Route path="/" component={Clients} />
```

Another fix would be to sadly avoid "compose" by doing this:

```
connect(
  (state, props) => ({
    clients: state.firestore.ordered.clients
  })
)(
  firestoreConnect([{ collection: "clients" }])(Clients)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem by changing these lines :

First I changed:

```
const clients = this.props.clients;
```

To :

```
const { clients } = this.props;
```

Then I changed :

```
Clients.prototype = {
  firestore: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  clients: PropTypes.array
};
```

To :

```
Clients.propTypes = {
  firestore: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  clients: PropTypes.array
};
```

and now it is working perfectly

Comment: The real fix is the prototype to propTypes, really hard to see this mistake.